# Is the Fuaran based on a real-world legend?

Tags: inspiration, night-watch-cycle

Sergei Lukyanenko's *Night Watch* series already has some links to real-world mythology via [the character of Gesar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140147/31394), and possibly [also Zabulon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/138547/31394). This made me wonder about the in-universe legend of the Fuaran, which was a pivotal plot point in book 3, *The Twilight Watch*. Is this also based on some real-life legend, or did Lukyanenko make it up out of whole cloth?

**Is there a legend of the Fuaran (or equivalent) in the real world?**

I did a web search for "Fuaran", but aside from Night Watch references, most of the results were touristy stuff in Scotland. But my web search defaults to English-language results, and this could well be from a Russian or Central Asian myth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, ***NO***.

1. Fuaran the book is named that way after its creator, witch Fuaran.
2. The witch came from the Indian city of [Kanakapura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanakapura):

   > Имя мое – Фуаран, я из женщин славного города Канакапури. ...
   >   Этот язык давно уже не звучал на Земле. Индологу он напомнил бы санскрит, но мало кто понял бы, что это пайшачи.
   >   ("Twilight Watch/"Сумеречный Дозор", *История третья, "Ничья Сила", Пролог*)
3. There is no mention of any Fuaran in Russian or English searches together with "Kanakapura".
4. There are no mentions of "Фуаран" in Russian search that aren't related to Watches books, Scotland, or a couple of things/people clearly named after the Fuaran from Watch books. I went down to ~10th page in Google search. Also, no Lukyanenko interviews mentioning Fuaran in this context.